# Command Pattern: Does my implementation make the point?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Asking for a review of my implementation of a command pattern. In a Editor, words can be entered and the entering of words can be undone.

General purpose Interface

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

The concrete write word command

```
// Command
public class WriteCommand implements Command {

    private Editor editor;
    private String word;

    public WriteCommand(String w, Editor e) {
        this.word = w;
        this.editor = e;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }

    public void execute() {
        this.editor.addToWordList(this.getWord());
    }

}
```

The undo command

```
public class UndoCommand implements Command {

    private Editor editor;


    public UndoCommand(Editor e) {
        this.editor = e;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        editor.removeFromWordList();
    }
}
```

The editor (i.e. receiver, i believe):

```
// Receiver
public class Editor {

    private List<String> wordList;

    public Editor() {
        wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addToWordList(String w) {
        this.wordList.add(w);
    }

    public void removeFromWordList() {
        this.wordList.remove(this.wordList.size()-1);
    }

    List<String> getWordList() {
        return this.wordList;
    }

}
```

The invoker keeping the command queue:

```
public class Invoker {
    private List<Command> undoList;
    private List<Command> redoList;


    public Invoker() {
        undoList = new ArrayList<>();
        redoList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void executeCommand(Command c) {
        undoList.add(c);
        c.execute();
    }
}
```

The client responsible for creating the commands:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Editor e = new Editor();

        Invoker invoker = new Invoker();

        invoker.executeCommand(new WriteCommand("Hello", e));
        invoker.executeCommand(new WriteCommand("World", e));
        System.out.println(e.getWordList());

        invoker.executeCommand(new UndoCommand(e));
        System.out.println(e.getWordList());

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to fit the bill. As general remarks: I would not include a reference to the editor in the `Command` itself - it makes more sense to make it a parameter for the `execute` method. That's more flexible, and you would have less trouble e.g. serializing the `Command` instances that way. Of course, you should not put the `UndoCommand` instances in the `undoList`. But to me, this seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Same as @MaartenBodewes, passing the "context" as parameter is more flexible than having it as an instance field. Just for the undo, it seems strange to use `removeFromWordList` your undo maye be used to undo other changes but also to remove another word; your user may want to have a menu to undo "Hello".. (think of your browser's history, you can go back to teh last "n" entries)

Comment: execute() should not take any arguments. Thats correct. Some commands may work over editor, some commands may work over other things. If execute accepted the editor than all commands have to. And that is not "more flexible". On other hand the undo logic should be contained within the commands themselves. Check my PoC PHP implementation, it is much more generic, but it should be well explanatory. https://github.com/slepic/PhpX/blob/master/src/CommandPattern/Undo/UndoableInvoker.php

Comment: The requirement for command pattern is that the command object contains all required state in itself. Adding parameters to the method breaks this requirement and it stops being a command pattern.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen The editors state is not part of the state of the command itself. There are certainly reasons to choose one over the other, but that's just bad argumentation. Similarly, I would not want every command in the same queue, so mixing commands for various parts of the program is not recommended. I don't want to have the "Save" action be in my `Edit -> Undo` queue, for one.

Comment: Editor's state is part of the command in the sense that the command has a reference to the editor it manipulates. It wouldn't make sense to create an undo command on one editor and execute it on another. Anyway, I didn't invent this. If you're not sure about it, read Gang of Four. Also implementing save as a command that is executed some time in the future is silly. Q generic command queue is not a thing. The queue always has a specific purpose.

Comment: I've read the book (although I am pretty sure that it is not *called* "Gang of Four"). I don't treat it as a bible though. Heck, I don't even treat the bible as a bible. I've also read e.g. Efficient Java, and commands can be made immutable and stateless *unless* you refer to `Editor` from within them. Serializing commands can be *very* useful, I hope you agree. OTOH, the editor state is dependent on the commands given and vice versa, so that says that including the editor reference can be useful. In that case you'll have to take extra care when serializing though.

Answer (score 2):

**If this was a school exercise**

It's a basic command pattern without any safety checks against programming errors. :) It would be a good idea to check that a word can not be removed from an empty list.

**If this was a job interview assignment**

While the code shows that you know how to code a command pattern it doesn't tell me if you understand why one would want to use it. Having WriteCommand and UndoCommand objects going around in isolation makes very little sense. And domain-wise, writing to a text editor with command objects is probably not something that I would do.

Instead put the command pattern into actual use by, for example, integrating it to the editor in the form of an undo/redo stack. Appending strings to the editor automatically create undo commands into the stack and performing the undo command executes the last command and adds a corresponding redo command into the redo stack.